# why glutFullScreen() crashes for subwindow on win7 Enterprise?

Tags: opengl, windows-7, glut

The same code runs well on 32bit xp, 64bit win7Ultr (32bit app). 
But when it comes to 64bit win7 enterprise on amd machine, it crashes. I tracked it down, 
and found out that :

```
    subWindow = glutCreateSubWindow(main_w, 0, 0, width, height);
glutDisplayFunc(displayf);
glClearColor(background[0], background[1],background[2], background[3]);
glutSetWindow(subWindow);

glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardf);
glutSpecialFunc(sqecial_keysf);
glutPositionWindow(0, 0);
glutReshapeWindow(width, height);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);


glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();    

glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0); 
//glutFullScreen( );  ----- crash!!

glutSwapBuffers( );
```

Any idea why this func crashes ? 
original glut library is used.

Comment: Are you using FreeGLUT or the old GLUT?

Comment: Is it right to call glutFullScreen() for subwindow?